# Fragments load data too slow

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am working on a project which is totally based on `Fragments` with `NavigationDrawer`.  Each fragment gets data from web services. A single fragment takes here so much time to load data. And one of all the fragments is a `Fragment` which has 10+ fragments using `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` and each fragment is showing data in a `ListView` and also takes so much time to load. I've tried many approaches and last approach is like:

```
public class CommodityFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
private boolean isViewShown = false;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (getView() != null) {
        isViewShown = true;
    } else {
        isViewShown = false;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.equity_activity, container, false);
    act = this.getActivity();
    return view;
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState1) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState1);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_equity);
    empty_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.empty);
    if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
        if (catListDao.size() > 0) {
            adapter = new AdvisorsAdapter(act,R.layout.custom_equity, catListDao);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // do some work here
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (!isViewShown) {
                                new FetchAllData(getActivity(), 2).execute();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();
        }
    } else {
        CustomToast toast = new CustomToast(getActivity(), "There is no internet connection!");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: create an `asynctask` for each network request and start each with `.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)`. This allows all of them to load at the same time.

Comment: @ColinGillespie you mean I should change `new FetchAllData(getActivity(), 2).execute();` into `new FetchAllData(getActivity(), 2).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);` ?

Comment: Yes that should do it. plain `execute()` adds all the request to a que, executing them one at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `execute()` on an `AsyncTask` adds it to a que shared by all of your `AsyncTask`'s. This means that each request to the server is made one at a time. By instead adding your task to a thread pool you can have many tasks executing at once.

```
myTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

For managing your network requests it would usually be better to use a **library** designed for doing so. I personally use Retrofit however others such as Volley, RoboSpice and OkHttp are a fine choice also.

Comment: I accepted it as answer because it worked in my entire app.

Comment: it really boost API request and app gets fast, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem. When working with tabLayout, each tabLayout was referring to a unique fragment. That created a lot overhead for the OS and when I Navigate to a tab, drawer's closing motion was cheesy.

**Android library "Volley"** was very helpful to decrease the time consuming api calling issue. Since it works on its own thread and it's own asynchronous queue.

Here is a example of how to use volley.

```
https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples
```

I could provide the complete sample code but it is under confidential agreement.

Comment: Volley can improve speed approx in milli seconds. I have resolved this issue by  Colin Gillespie's answer.

Comment: :-) 
OK bro. 
Might be I would try using as Colin Gillespie's suggested.

Comment: yes, you should also try once. Btw thanks for sharing your experience.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to use Retrofits concept.[Retrofits Demo](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit)